# Sine model of height as a function of distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, mathematical-modeling

[image]

I actually assumed the sine model to be:
$$y=A\sin(B(x-C))+D$$

We have: $$A=\frac{64-0}{2}=32$$

Now from the data we see that:
$$23=32\sin(40B-BC)+D$$
and $$23=32\sin(160B-BC)+D$$
$\implies$
$$160B-BC=2\pi+40B-BC$$
Which gives $B=\frac{\pi}{60}$.
But the book answer is $B=\frac{\pi}{100}$.
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sin (\alpha) = \sin (\beta)$, we can't conclude that $\alpha = 2\pi + \beta$.

The general solution is $\alpha = (2n+1)\pi - \beta $ or $\alpha = 2n \pi + \beta$

Now, the minimum is attained at $0$ and the maximum is attained at $100$.  We conclude that $C$ (horizontal shifting) is $50$ and $D=A=32$.

Now, let $x=100$, $64=32\sin(B(x-50))+32$,

$$\sin(50B)=1$$

We let $50B=\frac{\pi}{2}$, hence $B=\frac{\pi}{100}$.

Remark: Let's evaluate $40B-BC=\frac{\pi}{100}\left( 40-50\right)=-\frac{\pi}{10}$. Also $160B-BC=\frac{\pi}{100}\left( 160-50\right)=\frac{11\pi}{10}$, when we add them together, we get an odd multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: So is $C$ average of $x$ coordinates where the Max and Min of $y$ occurs?

Comment: yes, that is right.